# Trying to simplify a step-by-step macro in VBA

Tags: vba, textbox, activex, textcolor

I have a spreadsheet in which there are ActiveX textboxes that are linked to specific cells.  When the number in the cells change, the number in the textbox changes too.  Pretty simple.

I wanted the numbers in these textboxes to be red when there is a number above zero and white when the number is zero.  I've chosen white so that the zeros can't be seen at all on the printed page.  I have a very basic macro that does this:

```
Sub textbox_change()

Worksheets("PAGE01").E21.LinkedCell = "PAGE01!AB23"
If Worksheets("PAGE01").E21.Value > 0 Then
    Worksheets("PAGE01").E21.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Worksheets("PAGE01").E21.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If    

Worksheets("PAGE01").E22.LinkedCell = "PAGE01!AB24"
If Worksheets("PAGE01").E22.Value > 0 Then
    Worksheets("PAGE01").E22.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Worksheets("PAGE01").E22.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

End Sub
```

As you can see, the code for each textbox is completed one at a time.  How can I combine these so that the macro changes these colors at once, without having to have a block of code for each textbox?

Note:  I've only used two textboxes in the example, but I would like to have up to 48 of these boxes total.  That would be A LOT of redundancy when I'm positive that there's a much shorter way to take care of these pesky color changes.

Can you kind folks help out?  Very much appreciated...

Comment: Why are you updating the linked cells for all of your checkboxes?  Aren't they already set?

Comment: They are set to print as two separate reports.  One report will be the table that shows just the numbers and one report will print as a visual dashboard with images to visually represent what the numbers mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection and check for textboxes:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim t
    For Each t In Worksheets("PAGE01").OLEObjects
        'is it a textbox ?
        If t.progID = "Forms.TextBox.1" Then
            'check the name begins with "E"
            If t.Name Like "E*" Then
                'Set the forecolor: using the built-in color constants,
                '  but you could instead use specific RGB() values
                t.Object.ForeColor = IIf(t.Object.Value > 0, vbRed, vbWhite)
            End If
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```